# Nested routes in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, url-routing

I have an ember app which requires the following views:

---

- One to view all reviews that you've posted - `/reviews`
- One to view a user's profile - `/users/:id`
- One to view all reviews that another user has posted - `/users/:id/reviews`

I am struggling with the third one.

Here is my router.js

```
this.route('reviews', function() {
  this.route('show', { path: "/:id" });
});

this.route('users', function(){
  this.route('show', {path: '/:id'}, function () {
    this.route("reviews", function(){});
  });
});
```

My template for this route is in
`templates/users/show/reviews/index.hbs`

And my route is in `routes/users/show/reviews/index.js`

But when I visit `localhost:4200/users/1/reviews`, it shows the user profile path (`users/:id` - the second bullet point). Like *exactly* the same

How do I get this route to work with the correct template and route.js file?

Comment: What version of ember.js are you using?  Older versions require the use of `this.resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route should be like:

```
this.resource('reviews', function() {
  this.route('show', { path: '/:id'})
})
```

The previous means you will have available the following routes:

`/reviews` <- default route `index` for resource reviews

`/reviews/:id` <- this is the route `show`

And should have the following files:

Route      -> `app/routes/reviews/show.js`, `app/routes/reviews/index.js`

Controller -> `app/controllers/reviews/show.js`, `app/controllers/reviews/index.js`

Template   -> `app/templates/reviews/show.hbs`, `app/templates/reviews/index.hbs`

**Note that if  if you do not define any of previous files ember will generate one by default.**

For users should follow the same logic that previous definition.

```
this.resource('users', function() {
  this.resource('user', { path: '/:id' }, function () {
    this.route("reviews");
   });
});
```

Translate the previous definition for Users you will have the follow route.

`/users` <- the default index for resource users

`/users/:id` <- the default index for resource user

`/users/:id/reviews` <- the route for `reviews` inside `users`

Hope help you!